# how to obtain VC++ compiler-style help on GCC G++ compile/link errors (on linux)

Tags: gcc

I'm using VC++ as professional developer for more than 10 years and it has been good to me, now I'm trying to broaden my horizons and learn C++ development on Linux. 
On Windows things are simple, VC++ does it all (editing, project management, help, debugging), but on linux things are different, you have assemble your development environment from different tools. 
I'm still trying to tie things together, and one thing I still haven't figured out is how to decipher GCC (G++) errors when compiling/linking C++ apps on Linux (although I realize GCC is multi-platform, I'll refer to my linux experience here only).
In VC++, things are very clear: If during compilation VC++'s compiler encounters error in program, it will create new entry in 'output' window with the 'compiler error ID'. Example:

c:\projectA\fileB.cpp(38) : error C2228: left of '.cout' must have class/struct/union

From here, you can click on the line in question in 'output' window, press F1, and 'Microsoft Document Browser' app will start (if it wasn't started already), which will load MSDN help file describing compile error connected to the compiler error ID (in example it's C2228), usually with sample you can check out to figure out what's wrong with your code. If you don't have MDB installed, you can always search on the web for C2228 and get the same help page, optionally finding other people's web pages describing their experience with this error.
The same thing is with linking, you'll get 'linker error ID' (e.g. LNK1123), which you can use to find help either locally or on web.

Try as I might, I can't find this kind of functionality in GCC's G++. All I can see is bunch of less experienced GCC developers asking another bunch of more experienced GCC developers to analyze their code based on descriptive compiler/linker errors with no associated error IDs. 
Is there tool(set) that provides VC++ compiler-style help on GCC G++ compile/link errors for linux?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use qtcreator. At least it can show the errors in a more comprehensive way comparable to the VC++, that is, it can locate the error position and highlight the error line and variables.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, while I wanted to explore QtCreator mainly because of it's promise for visual support of GDB compiler and integration with GDB's 'Archer Python' version, It doesn't even wanna start on my Ubuntu 10.04. I need industrial strenght tools (we all do), and this was enought for me not to follow this path.

Answer (score 0):

If you can an alternative might be to use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) instead.  It gives **much** better error messages than g++.  It compiles most code these days (but it still a work in progress).  Highly recommended.

Alternatively (as another poster has mentioned) you could use an IDE such as Eclipse to capture the error messages, though I don't think that adds anything beyond taking you to the line number on double-click.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I don't wanna go opening another can of worms, there are enough blind alleys on *nix. I've tried so far Eclipse, NetBeans, MonoDevelop, QtCreator (I've tried, see above :), they are all too slow, and still no help for GCC or any hint on how to get it consistently. I'm trying now with Code::Blocks, but debugging is ridiculous (I've tried debugging small app with 2 threads, but Code::Blocks doesn't

Comment: Sadly, it appears that I'll have to go with emacs (or vim) and extra tools, but It's beyond my comprehension that after full week of researching the web I didn't find single post that would give selection of tools that would give best performance and user experience closest to that of VC++. Apparently MS isn't as bad as everyone tries to paint them, certainly not when it comes to VC++